# n*n matrix of 0s and 1s in python

Tags: python, numpy, tile

How to create an `‘n*n’` checkerboard matrix with the values alternate `0 and 1`, using the `tile function`.

For example:
when n has a value of 2, Output should be:

```
[[0 1] 
 [1 0]]
```

I am able to create a `matrix with 0 and 1`, but they are not appearing alternatively, below is what i tried:

```
import numpy as np
n = 4
arr = ([0,1])
print(np.tile(arr,(n,n//2)))
```

output I got:

```
[[0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1]]`
```

output I want:

```
[[0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]]`
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple way using numpy could be to define a vector of `0s` and `1s` of size `n` and take advantage of broadcasting to create a `nxn` checkerboard:

```
def checkerboard(n):
    a = np.resize([0,1], n)
    return np.abs(a-np.array([a]).T)
```

###### Sample use -

```
checkerboard(2)
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0]])

checkerboard(4)
array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

###### Details -

The above works by initially creating a length `n` 1D vector of `0s` and `1s` using `np.resize`:

```
import numpy as np
n = 3

np.resize([0,1], n)
array([0, 1, 0])
```

And then subtracting its transposed (2D), which will result in a broadcast array of shape `(n,n)`, with negative and positive `1s`:

```
a-np.array([a]).T
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  1],
       [-1,  0, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  1],
       [-1,  0, -1,  0]])
```

We just need to take the absolute value of it and we have a checkerboard matrix.

Comment: This is excellent

Comment: I want to achieve this specifically using tile() function. Please suggest how to do that.

Comment: np.abs(a-np.array([a]).T)
How it performs, can you break and explain

Comment: Added some explanations @octogenex

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy fancy [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html), no need to use [np.tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
import numpy as np

def tiling(n):
    result = np.zeros((n, n))
    result[::2, 1::2] = 1
    result[1::2, ::2] = 1
    return result


print(tiling(2))
print()
print(tiling(4))
```

**Output**

```
[[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]

[[0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

Comment: I want to achieve this specifically using tile() function.

Comment: @Manish i have updated this answer i hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line numpy solution. That said, I think Daniel's response is much more readable and probably more efficient.

If `n` is odd then `np.arange(n*n).reshape(n,n)%2` gives the correct result. However, if `n` is even, then all the rows and columns will be the same (like your result). We can fix this by subtracting one from every other row.

```
tile = (np.arange(n*n).reshape(n,n)-np.arange(n).reshape(n,1)*(n%2+1))%2
```

Equivalently,

```
tile = (np.arange(n*n).reshape(n,n,order='F')-np.arange(n)*(n+1))%2
```